# WinCE: 10053 error during connect

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce

I wrote a Bluetooth client program for a wince 4.2 device. The device discovery works fine. However, when I attempt to connect to a PC, the connect function immediately returns with error code `10053`. The connection request was being processed by the PC with a prompt to enter the authentication code but the wince device doesn’t seem to wait.

What could be causing this issue? I am using the following steps (removed error handling for simplicity):

```
WSAStartup(..)…////was successful.

SOCKET m_Socket =Socket (AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM); //was successful.

SOCKADDR_BTH sClinet;
memset (&sClinet, 0, sizeof(sClinet));
sClinet.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
sClinet.btAddr = btd.btaddr; ; //BT_ADDR of the PC obtained via Device Discovery..
sClinet.port = BT_PORT_ANY; //I did try 0, did not help!
sClinet.serviceClassId = RFCOMM_PROTOCOL_UUID; 

int nConErr = connect (m_Socket, (SOCKADDR *)&sClinet, sizeof(sClinet));
```

`nConErr` returns `10053` immediately. It doesn’t even wait, even though the PC recognized the connection and prompted a message to enter the PIN for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing it looks like it is a pairing/authentication problem. You should consider in using also `setsockopt` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms863347.aspx

You should try to use `SO_BTH_AUTHENTICATE` option which according to MSDN:

> On connected socket, triggers authentication. On not connected socket, forces authentication on connection. For incoming connection this means that connection is rejected if authentication cannot be performed.

So before calling `connect` function you should set options to your socket.